# Using random forest model to predict values from a new dataset

Tags: random-forest, predict

I have built a random forest model to predict 'size' from several values of 'shape'. I now want to input new data, not from the data the model was created on, and for it to predict the values of 'size'. I was wondering how to format this, and how to get the predicted results. I have attached what the original data looks like, as well as the new data I want to input into my model .  Should I change X_test to be the new data? I have also attached the code I used to create the model. Thank you so much!
[image]

[image]

```
X = dataset[headers]
y = dataset["size"]

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
sc = StandardScaler()
scaled_X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
scaled_X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, random_state = 0)
classifier = classifier.fit(scaled_X_train,y_train)
y_predicted = classifier.predict(scaled_X_test)
```

Comment: How many unique values are in `size`? Also, did you include the `untitled` and `minutes` columns in your training set? Finally, please don't use pictures of your data; that makes it harder to replicate.

Comment: I think I got it figured out, thank you!